# How to change audio clip in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I have this code:

```
public AudioClip rsound;
public AudioClip gsound;

AudioSource audioSource;

private void OnEnable()
{
    if (LastCube == null)
        LastCube = GameObject.Find("Start").GetComponent<MovingCube>();

    CurrentCube = this;

    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = GetRandomColor();
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(LastCube.transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, LastCube.transform.localScale.z);

    audioSource = GameObject.Find("Start").gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

}

void PlayOnDrop()
{
    audioSource.clip = rsound;
    audioSource.Play();
}
```

I want to first play the `gsound`, and then play the `rsound` after a click.
How can I change the `AudioClip` value?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the best way is Create a Audio controller in a Dontdestory with singleton.

Write code playAudio with Argument as Audio clip